# Dynamic element configuration using context Menu using c# Selenium Chrome webdriver

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

Wanted to configure page element dynamically of any page element using c# Selenium Chrome Web Browser context menu right click on particular web element.

Code snippet:

```
 string docPage = idriver.PageSource.ToString();
        doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(idriver.PageSource);
```

Comment: So what is your question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Once to page get load,want to right click on any page element and extract the element id,class,href etc instead hardcode id,class,xpath and get the elements so that user can map the any element as per their choice.

Comment: unable to get element on right click on particular page element.